# WordPress HTTP ERROR 500 while updating plugins

Tags: wordpress

I am getting HTTP ERROR 500 after updating my plugins. Not all the plugins succeeded and then when I tried to reload the site, I get the error.

> This page isn’t working www.mysite.com is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Any tips would be welcome

Comment: This might help: [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your plug ins folder, which will effectively deactivate all of them, then slowly add them back in one at a time till you find the one causing the problem.

500 is an internal server error, so it isn't that it can't find the page, rather that it can't process it. One of the plug ins is causing the site not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to extend your current .htaccess file setup?

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
memory_limit = 96M
max_execution_time = 300
```